# Ember - #each pass the instance of the model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

For a small webapp I'm trying to do the following:

I have a list of objects (achievement-model)that's being served through a json api

**Router**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model:function(){
      return this.store.find('achievement');
     });
});
```

**Model**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

**Template**

```
     {{#each a in model}}
       <div>
          <h4>{{a.name}}</h4> 
          <p>{{a.description}}</p>
          <button {{action 'addThis'}}/>
       </div>
      {{/each}}
```

The setup of the app is that there is a list of achievements. I want one list of achievements in a database. Every user that logs in can add with the button his own achievements to his profile. If a user logs in he should see the list of all the achievements but the one he already added to his profile should have a green background color and the button removed. I know this can be done with if-statements etc.

The problem however is, how do i pass the specific model to the controller so i can log this to the userprofile? I tried the following:

```
     <button {{action 'addThis' a}}/>
```

and then in the controller

```
    actions: 
         addThis: function(obj){
              console.log(obj);
         });
```

which logs the object, but somehow I can't acces it to get let's say the name or id to copy it to the user-profile.

I also don't know if this is the best approach for what I'm trying to achieve?

**Edit**
I think this has something to do with promises. I can see the data is logged in the above console.log. I just don't know how to target it. it's wrapped in _data. I tried the afterModel to wait untill everything's loaded, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: in the action addThis, doesn't obj.name works ?

Comment: no, the obj.name doesn't work

Comment: try the itemcontroller as in the answer i've written

Comment: Likely a silly question.... are you using `obj.get('title')`?

Comment: that works! Can you just give me some insight on the "how" and "why"?

Answer (score 0):

What you could is to use an ItemController, e.g. which handles each item in the ArrayController,

e.g.

```
{{#each a in model  itemController="achievement"}}
       <div>
          <h4>{{a.name}}</h4> 
          <p>{{a.description</p>
          <button {{action 'addThis'}}/>
       </div>
{{/each}}
```

Since the itemController is "achievement", by naming convention, the controller becomes

```
App.AchievementController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
 init: function() {

     var name = this.get('name');
     var description = this.get('description');
   }

});
```